# PSExec registry file remotly

Tags: powershell, psexec

I am trying to execute a PowerShell to execute a reg file remotly

This is what I have at the moment:

```
$computer = 'IP';
$username = 'user';
$password = 'password';
$reg      = 'regedit /s //ip/teste.reg';

$reg_command = "psExec -i -d -c -f -s \\$computer -u $computer\$username -p $password `"$reg`"";

Write-Output "Inserting regestry file...";

Invoke-Expression $reg_command;
```

I have psExec in my computer, but I don't know how I would add the path executable for PSExec in the code.

Comment: PSExec is on your machine no on the remote machine.  Never use Invoke-Expression, [here's why --- Invoke-Expression is evil](https://www.bing.com/search?q=invoke-expression+evil&form=ANNTH1&refig=6889e08bda7b494a86c92dbc12dbfa65&sp=-1&pq=invoke-expression+evil&sc=6-22&qs=n&sk=&cvid=6889e08bda7b494a86c92dbc12dbfa65), use Invoke-Command. [PSExec allows hitting a remote machine without the need to PowerShell at all.](https://www.bing.com/search?q=psexec%20remote%20registry&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=psexec%20remote%20registry&sc=5-22&sk=&cvid=D6413E834E0146A7B43F396CC9EAC5B0), but you could, but...

Comment: Also, for running external commands via PowerShell, see my answer/comment here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62048859/command-prompt-executes-this-correctly-but-powershell-doesnt/62057429#62057429